# UITableView prototype cell in swift not displaying content in Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: uitableview, xcode7.3

The UITableView not displaying content.It was working before but after updating to xcode 7.3.1 it's not working.Anyone faced this issue ? I have correctly given the cell identifier,Cell subclass name,delegates and datasource etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's worked for me..!
Do check mark the 2 boxes as in the attached image.We need to do this for all UI elements in cell content view.

[image]